# Object Recognition with Android

Tags: android

I've been thinking about working on an application. You take a picture of something at a yard sale and it compares it against an image database.

For example say you take a picture of a spoon, and compares the image taken against images in the database and throws back to the user the top 5 possible matches.

Is this possible with current Android?

If so point me in the right direction, for stuff I'd need.

Thanks,
abolbridge

Look forward to your guys feedback.

Comment: I think that will be very difficult to achieve. You have pictures that vary in so many parameters (angle, light, distance, focus, etc....) so that it is imho almost impossible to match it with other real world objects. There just too many combinations.

Comment: Ok assuming I start small and just take a few pictures of spoons in a standard format (ie same angle, light, distance, etc.)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is rather possible, but too much CPU consuming and therefore not possible on Android itself. You'd have to build a serverside application for that.

It is going to be hard though. Quite.

Take a look at Google Goggles for an idea. The image processing is entirely made on the server side.

Comment: Just another remark: if you really want object recognition to work, you'll have to either standardize de angles for the user's photos or have a database with all(most) possible angles for each and every object.

Answer (score 1):

Check out openCV, as it contains a lot of useful object recognition functions and can be used on android.  However, this approach will push the limits of the phones CPU and more so, its memory when using higher resolution images. A server-side implementation may be more appropiate.